# What is the Xcode 11 beta Colors library for in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode11

In the nib editor (Interface Builder) in Xcode 11 beta, when you edit a storyboard or xib file, when you summon the Library, it now has three sections: Objects, Images, and Colors. What's the Colors section for? I can see that it lists named colors from the asset catalog, but I can't seem to *do* anything with that list; if I drag a color onto the Canvas or a view or whatever, nothing happens.